# Wifi constantly disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I've been having problems with my WiFi over the last few weeks where my Internet would stop working even though it shows as connected. This is only happening on this laptop. Every other device in the house works without any problem. It's fixed by running diagnose but after a few minutes it happens again. I've updated all the drivers and that didn't help at all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here's my `ipconfig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ILuvCookie
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Połączenie lokalne* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Ad
apter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 32-3A-64-E7-1E-9A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Połączenie lokalne* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adap
ter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-3A-64-E7-1E-9B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 30-3A-64-E7-1E-9A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f1ec:7efe:b1e7:96d9%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 maja 2015 21:21:00
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 27 maja 2015 23:20:59
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 137378404
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-9B-69-A5-F0-76-1C-0B-AB-D6

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dobrynet.eu
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F0-76-1C-0B-AB-D6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:38c0:3cc6:3f57:ff99(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::38c0:3cc6:3f57:ff99%11(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 452984832
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-9B-69-A5-F0-76-1C-0B-AB-D6

   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{468EB845-EDDA-4802-AD45-E0FFC9100041}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Karta Microsoft ISATAP #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Have all Windows Updates and driver updates been applied? Is there a BIOS update related to this?

Comment: Can you show this information on the adapter in question when its working and when its not working?  Does the USB adapter do this on any other device?

Comment: its not a usb adapter, its build in my laptop. intel(r) dual band wireless-ac 3160 and realtek pcie gbe family controller, if thats what you mean.

Comment: oh and while running diagnose when its not working i receive the message, Default gateway is unavailable

Comment: Sounds like somehow you lost your default route (or are conatantly)

Comment: Any idea h9w to fix it?

Comment: Your title says your wifi is disconnecting but your description says the wifi is staying connected.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your adapter (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160) is on the border of or outside of the connection radius. Try moving your machine closer to the router. If this works you may need to purchase a repeater to get a good connection where you are.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be it, it keeps happening even when I'm right beside the router

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I fixed it somehow.
My router dhcp dns was set to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 changed it to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 and everything seems to be fine since i did it

Comment: I would consider resetting your router to default settings...

Answer (score 0):

If your ISP supports you should use your private IP from your routers DHCP and the others from your ISP. In any case it is the most secure method to set your adapters IP fields to automatic, if you have no other reason to set them manually, but then you have to watch for IP changes by your ISP. The symptoms may be similar to the case you experienced and you have to get the right IP´s by contacting your ISP.